# How to use alternate_urls setting in manifest

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying for quite some time to understand this:

In the [Chrome settings documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override) they claim to have an `alternate_url` option in the JSON:

```
 "alternate_urls": [
          "http://www.moo.__MSG_url_domain__/s?q={searchTerms}",
          "http://www.noo.__MSG_url_domain__/s?q={searchTerms}"
        ],
```

However, I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation how am I suppoused to use this.
I've tried setting the `search_url` to a page that returns 500,404 errors and you would expect the alternate URL to work, but it didn't.

Does anyone know how do I get it to use the alternate URL or what does it use for?

Thanks in advance,

Eric

Comment: Judging by [prepopulated_engines.json](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/search_engines/prepopulated_engines.json) in the source code and other C++ files in that directory, it appears that `alternate_urls` is used to describe possible variations of the search URL so that the browser is able to collect the keywords used during searching (for example, via the search site itself) under one entry for the engine. One use case I know of is the per-engine autocomplete dropdown displayed in the address bar. You can submit a request on https://crbug.com to clarify the documentation.